# sql server stored procedure - bit type

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

is input to a bit type 0,1 and NULL ? or is it only 0,1 ?

in sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Unclear. Is this question about parameters of stored proc or?

Comment: Easy to test yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be either - it depends on if you're "Allowing Nulls" on the column or not.

```
BIT NOT NULL
```

allows for 1 and 0

```
BIT NULL
```

allows for 1, 0, and null.

After looking at the title of the question... I guess that could potentially change things a bit (lolol). if using a bit parameter or variable, then the values can be 0, 1, or null.

Sorry I missed the reference to the stored procedure as it was only in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Bit can have values 0,1 and NULL

REF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms177603.aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms177603.aspx) it can be 0,1 and NULL.

Answer (score 1):

By default **[BIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx)** can be `NULL`, `0`, `1`.

You can restrict nulls in following:

```
BIT NOT NULL
```